# openai.error.InvalidRequestError while trying to create an embedding

Tags: python, azure, openai-api, embedding, chatgpt-api

I'm trying to create a embeddings of PDF pages of multiple PDF documents in python with the Azure OpenAI API.

I basically just call in a loop for each page chunk for each pdf file:

```
embedding = get_embedding(page_text_chunk, engine = "text_embedding")
```

And it works for many of the PDFs, but one PDF throws the following error:

```
openai.error.InvalidRequestError: '$.input' is invalid.
```

The weird thing is, that if I execute the crashing PDF file alone, it doesn't throw the error and I can't make sense of this and I don't understand what the error means.

Answer (score 2):

The mentioned error `openai.error.InvalidRequestError: '$.input' is invalid.` is a known issue, encountered when creating embeddings with large datasets. This issue is documented [here](https://github.com/openai/openai-python/issues/519).

To handle and troubleshoot this, you can make sure below pointers holds true:

- The `input` parameter cannot exceed 2048 elements (chunks of text) in a list.
- The total count of tokens across all elements in the `input` list must not exceed 1,000,000 tokens
- Each individual array element (chunk of text) cannot be more than 8191 tokens.
- The input parameter should not contain any BLANK/EMPTY/NULL content in the list of paragraphs.